# Named parameters not working in shell function

Tags: shell, getopts

I have this shell script that is supposed to accept two optional parameters `start` and `end` from command line:

```
function foo {
    # -s : start
    # -e : end
    while getopts 's:e:' arg
    do
        case ${arg} in
            s) start=${OPTARG};;
            e) end=${OPTARG};;
            *) return 1 # illegal option
        esac
    done

    echo "start, end:"
    echo $start, $end

    unset start
    unset end
}
```

I get random results from the runs. Here is a list of runs (in chronological order), and their outputs:

1.

```
$ foo
start, end:
,
```

2.

```
$ foo -s 2011
start, end:
2011,
```

3.

```
$ foo -e 2015
start, end:
,
```

4.

```
$ foo -s 2011 -e 2016
start, end:
, 2016
```

5.

```
$ foo -s 2011 -e 2016
start, end:
,
```

6.

```
$ foo
start, end:
,
```

7.

```
$ foo -s 2011 -e 2016
start, end:
2011, 2016
```

8.

```
$ foo -s 2011 -e 2016
start, end:
,
```

Please help. The requirement is as simple as the first two lines of this post. Any alternative method works too, but I would love to know what I'm doing wrong here. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function sets global variable `OPTIND` due to invocation of getopts. You can prevent this by adding `local OPTIND` at the beginning of your function (you might want to do that for variables `end` and `start` as well).